# how to find a particular string in the sentence and remove the string in sql

Tags: c#, sql

I have to remove the particular value from the sentence which is stored in SQL database. Sentence will look like this:

```
1 Payments:ihj - CHENNAI-HIRE:54005-TN69AZ54008,4021-TN69AZ54005

2 Payments:ihj - CHENNAI-HIRE:54004-TN69AZ54008,4021-TN69AZ54005,54005-TN69AZ54008
```

In above sentence `54004` is the number which I will pass as parameter to SQL. This is the number which I want to remove from this line but same number is present in this line as `TN69AZ54005`. This number should not be disturbed, and in another payment we have same amount in another place. Can anyone help on this?

I tried with this sql query

```
declare @text int=4019

select SUBSTRING(notes,CHARINDEX(cast(@text as varchar),notes),
                             len(notes)-CHARINDEX(',',notes)+1) 
                             from Accounts.TransactionNotes 
                             where TransactionID=1978
```

If I use this query it will affect including this line `TN69AZ54005`

Comment: If all your sentences are roughly the same, you can search for **:54005** and replace it with **:** - that way **TN69AZ54005** will remain untouched

Comment: It will differ in entry.In second payment you can see that.

Comment: In that case - also search for **,54005**.

Comment: You basically want to replace some substring somewhere and somewhere not. You should specify exactly and unambiguously where you want to replace it and where not. Without this specification it is not possible to implement it. Btw do you really think that storing coma separated values in db is a good idea? Btw2 54004 is not part of TN69AZ54005 in any way.

Comment: i want to delete this string from the sentence.i just past this for example

Comment: You have strings A and B. B is substring of A. You want to replace B in A under some conditions. So, write down the conditions when and only when you want to replace it.

Comment: can you please see that below query.that is the position i want to delete.can you please give some example how to delete that please

Answer (score 1):

I can see that you've included a C# tag into your question. Then probably the easiest way is just to select all necessary rows using your app, then iterate through them and change the strings to your needs (using eg. PHP preg_replace() equivalent) and update the SQL rows.

I believe that is the easiest way, not really SQL solution but still...

Comment: it is the part of sp work.so c# code can not handle that

Comment: C# tag, SQL tag, how PHP is even relevant?

Answer (score 1):

```
update <table> set notes = replace(notes, 'HIRE:'+ str(<inputparam>),'HIRE:') where transactionid=<transactionid>

update <table> set notes = replace(notes, ','+ str(<inputparam>),',') where transactionid=<transactionid>
```

You will need to find something to prefix your `inputpram` value, like in above example I am using `"HIRE:"` or a comma.

Another way could be to use REGEXP  to find the whole word, then one one query would suffice. But I haven't tried it.

> The problem here is not the query but the person who designed the
>   database.

Answer (score 0):

I`m not sure is it this what you want but I will past my code. :)

```
-- for test create #temp
SELECT 
A.DATA
INTO #Temp
FROM
(
SELECT 'Payments:ihj - CHENNAI-HIRE:54005-TN69AZ54008,4021-TN69AZ54005' AS DATA 
UNION
SELECT 'Payments:ihj - CHENNAI-HIRE:54004-TN69AZ54008,4021-TN69AZ54005,54005-TN69AZ54008' AS DATA
) AS A

GO 

-- this you want?
UPDATE #Temp
SET DATA = REPLACE(DATA,'54004','')
GO

-- select changed data
SELECT * FROM #Temp
```